How to expand the assumptions for the nonlinear heat equation to obtain uniqueness?
Let $n\geq3$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ be bounded, $g\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $f:\ L^2\big((0,T),L^2(\Omega) \big) \longrightarrow L^2\big((0,T),H^{-1}(\Omega) \big)$ satisfies
\begin{align*}
\exists L>0:\ \big|f(u)\big|\,\leq\,L|u|^\alpha\tag1
\end{align*}
where $1\leq \alpha<2^*-1\ \ \displaystyle\left(2^*=\frac{2n}{n-2}\right)$, and
\begin{align*}
uf(u)\,\leq\,0,\tag2
\end{align*}
for all $u\in L^2\big((0,T),L^2(\Omega) \big)$. Then the heat equation
\begin{align*}
(P)\left\{\begin{aligned}
u_t-\Delta u&=f(u) &&\Omega\times(0,T),
\\ u&=0 &&\partial\Omega\times(0,T),
\\\ u(0)&=g &&\Omega.
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{align*}
has a weak solution.
Applying Lerray-Schauder fixed point theorem, we could show the existence of the weak solution of $(P)$. After that, I wonder if we can go further to show the uniqueness of this solution by adding more assumption on $f$ ? Thanks.
